# What is the best way to join multiple datasets on multiple columns in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have multiple (8-10) different datasets, all of which have a primary key (Name), some common columns and then some individual columns each. For example, table 1 might consist of Name, Date, Age, Username, LoginTime; table 2 Name, Date, MothersName,LoginTime, Age; table3 Name, Username, School, University, Age and so on and so forth.
Ideally I would like this all merged into a single table with unique columns: Name, Date, Age, Username, LoginTime, MothersName, School, University.

I know Access doesn't allow the use of covalesce - how can I go about creating this master table? I know what order I would like SQL to look in i.e. if Age is not in table 3, only then look in table 2 (even if table 2 has a value), and only then look in table 1 for that given Name. However I cannot work out how best to do the join so I don't get table1.Age, table2.Age, and table3.Age across all of my common fields...

Comment: Will common fields ever have disparity? For instance will *Age* ever differ across the tables by given *Name*?

Comment: Names make very poor primary keys. What if there are multiple John Smith with the same age and same university but they are really different people? Or John Smith age is different in each table but really the same person? Really should save birthdate and calculate age although that would not solve all issues with this data.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I recognise that. The column headings here are examples - the dataset does not actually contain Names.

Comment: Common fields might have disparity, but I am able to define the order of priority in which I would like to pull into the 'master' (for lack of a better word) table I.e. Pull Age from table 2, and only look at table 1 if table 2 is null